# How can I add keywords in my android app for local app search?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-manifest

I tried with

in Manifests.xml

```
   <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
        android:value=".MyActivity" />
```

in activity tag

```
<meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
</intent-filter>
```

And added this provider.

```
<provider android:authorities=".search.MySuggestionProvider"
            android:name=".search.MySuggestionProvider" />
```

searchable.xml is like this

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="@string/searchHint"
    android:includeInGlobalSearch="true"
    android:label="@string/searchLabel"
    android:searchSettingsDescription="@string/global"
    android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.example.search.MySuggestionProvider"
    android:searchSuggestSelection=" ? " />
```

and created MySuggestionProvider like this

```
package com.example.search

import android.content.SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider

class MySuggestionProvider: SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider() {
    init {
        setupSuggestions(AUTH, DATABASE_MODE_QUERIES)
    }

    companion object {
        private const val AUTH = "com.example.search.MySuggestionProvider"
    }
}
```

here's strings.xml.

```
    <string name="searchLabel">kakao</string>
    <string name="searchHint">카톡</string>
    <string name="global">안녕</string>
```

But this is not working. I guess this is for other usage. Some apps, for example, kakaotalk. I can search with 'kakao', 'katalk', '카톡', '카카오톡', etc.

I think there must be some configuration somewhere in the project. How can I achieve this?